# PyCaret NLP assign_model(lda) assigns topics on empty rows

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling, pycaret

I'm using pycaret to create_model(lda) and then using that for assign_model(lda). Not sure if I'm doing something that I'm not supposed to do during pre-processing. Any help is much appreciated

```
   #create model
   lda = create_model('lda')
```

```
   lda_df = assign_model(lda)
   lda_df
```

The resulting dataframe has the topics assigned on top rows where the rows are empty for other column values and the actual values are pushed below.

[image: Top Few Rows with empty column values have topics assigned to them]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset_index() solved this. There were some subsetting that was done earlier.